# How to loop values in a Google Sheets Node.js script?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to insert values in the next row after executing this script. The difference between the rows is 13.

How I would I loop this script so that after execution, the values appear in the next row?

```js
// Google Sheets API
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const creds = require('./client_secret.json');
var counter = 0; // Used to debug cellnumber association

    // Define Spreadhseet Scope
    const cells = await promisify(sheet.getCells)({
        'min-row': 1,
        'max-row': 106,
        'min-col': 1,
        'max-col': 13,
        'return-empty': true
    });

    // Get a list of all the cells and relate them to a counter for assigning variables
    for(const cell of cells){
        counter++;
        console.log(`${counter-1} -- ${cell.row}, ${cell.col}: ${cell.value}`);
    }

    /* Assign all variables to related spreadsheet cell */
    cells[17].value = value + '%';
    cells[17].save();
    cells[18].value = value + '%';
    cells[18].save();
    cells[19].value =  value+ '%';
    cells[19].save();
    cells[20].value =  value+ '%' ;
    cells[20].save();
    cells[21].value = value+ '%';
    cells[21].save();
    cells[22].value =  value + '%';
    cells[22].save();


}

sendToGoogleSpreadsheet();
```

Comment: Kindly include libraries that you're using in the script

Comment: I am using the Google Drive API
- Webserver (node.js)
- application data

Comment: Where is `sheet` defined?

Comment: Adjusted the code, followed this instruction video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGN6EUi4Yio

Comment: As I said, [Edit] your question to include the libraries that you're using. You're using this unofficial library https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet . And it's based on Google drive api(not sheets api). I don't think many people use  this library. So, the chances of getting a answer is pretty low. I suggest using the official node library [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) to accomplish what you want to do.